# Setting up Git Server on windows remote computer

Tags: bash, git, web, deployment, continuous-integration

I want to perform CI/CD on remote server running on windows for hosting my VueJs project. For doing that I have performed the following steps

1. I have added my ssh of my local machine to remote server as authorised keys and I am  able to access the admin(cmd) remote server via ssh by using the following command.

   ```
   ssh remote_server@<ip_address>
   ```

Using the above command the git bash opens cmd with following location `c:/users/remote_user1`  of remote server where I had added ssh of my local machine as authorized key.

2. I created bare git repo in `C:/users/remote_user1` by logging in remote computer by rdp using the following command

   ```
   git init test.git --bare
   ```
3. I gave Full access rights to `test.git` from remote server
4. I tried to clone `test.git` on my local machine using the command from git bash

   ```
   git clone ssh://remoteserver@<ip_address>:/test.git
   ```

when I use the command from my local machine I get the error message from git bash

```
fatal: ''/test.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am not able to understand what am I am doing wrong here, Please guide me on this.

Comment: If you created the repo in the home folder of the user you are logging in with, remove the `/` before the repo name in your clone command. It is unlikely that you are creating the git repo in the root of the filesystem.

Comment: hi @fredrik, I have already tried doing that, I get invalid url error after I remove / from git bash.
``` fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax ```

Comment: Then give the full absolute path on the remote server.

Comment: Have also tried doing that , still no luck

Answer (score 1):

The format for ssh urls must be one of :

```
# 'ssh://' url :
ssh://remoteserver@<ip_address>/test.git

# scp-like syntax :
remoterserver@<ip_address>:test.git
```

([link to docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_ssh_protocol))

The url you posted contains a `:/` which makes it a mixture of both, you should modify this url to match one of the two accepted formats.